# DC AC Inverter topologies

Tags: transformer, ac, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, inverter

I am trying to get a deeper understanding of sine wave inverters (like this [one](https://fr.ryobitools.eu/outils-de-jardin/outils-de-recharge/transformateurs/ry18bi150a/ry18bi150a-0/)) and thereby came across different topologies like a Push pull inverter with a center taped transformer or a full bridge configuration as seen in a class D amplifier.

I think that the center taped transformer setup requires less transistors but a bigger transformer whereas the full bridge option gets along with a smaller transformer.

Nonetheless I am not able to find more details or an overview of maybe other different existing topologies e.g. When to use which topology for a special power rating.

Am I looking for the wrong buzzwords or can somebody help me out with a link to books/application notes/etc describing inverter topologies and their characteristics?

Comment: Just google "inverter topology" and you get  lot of results: papers, white papers, etc. You might be interested in 3-ph inverters, single-phase, multi-level, neutral point clamped, etc. This for mainly "industrial" applications, including e.g. PV generation, power drives, etc. (cannot attach the screenshot to a comment)

Comment: The small  (<5kW) sine wave inverters I've come across use a buck or other converter to boost the DC up to 320V (assuming 240VAC output) then use a  H bridge and pwm to synthesize the sine wave followed by a RC filter to clean it up. A class D amplifier in other words.

Comment: @Kartman That is a really cool topology, although without isolation but probably cheaper!

Comment: @Kartman a buck converter doesn't boost voltages.

Comment: Yes, I did intend to write ‘boost’. Been having buck converter issues at the office, so it stuck in my brain!

Answer (score 1):

The transformer size is slightly larger for centre tapped (because slightly more copper is needed in the transformer primary)

In a teardown video they show the 120V version of this inverter with two large MOSFETs on a heatsink, so probably a centre tapped transformer.

In a compact inverter like this one the transformer probably runs at a high frequency to produce a high DC voltage that is then chopped to make AC at 50Hz.